# Google Signin for iOS - YouTube Channel ID

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, google-signin, youtube-data-api

I have follows the instructions and implement Google Signin for iOS in test application.
After getting the user profile & token, I want to get the user YouTube channel ID.
I have tried to use the user access token with the following URL but I got exception of "Insufficient Permission"
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&maxResults=50&mine=true&access_token={oauth_token}

How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 4):

Google Signin for iOS implementation which allow you yo signin with your google account. In order to have that ability to get YouTube data it require additional scope configuration as follows:

```
let scope: NSString = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
let currentScopes: NSArray = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = currentScopes.arrayByAddingObject(scope)
```

Now, you can run the following YouTube data API with Access Token:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token={oauth_token}
```

The access token, you will get from `user.authentication.accessToken`